# MonthYearPickerView Library Swift 2.0 Issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift2, nsdatecomponents

I'm using [MonthYearPickerView](https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift) Library in my project and it is running fine in Swift 1.2 now I'm trying to convert it into Swift 2.0 and I'm getting some issues.

I changed the calendar components into the code below under the commented code but I have an issue `Cannot convert value of type 'NSDateComponents' to expected argument type 'Int'` when I'm trying to append or minus the value of the year. So please how could I fix this issue?

class MonthYearPickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    var years: [Int] = []
    if years.count == 0 {

        //var year = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.component(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: NSDate())

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var year = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate:NSDate())

        for i in 1...10 {
            years.append(year)
            year++
        }
    }
    self.years = years

    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    //var month = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.component(.CalendarUnitMonth, fromDate: NSDate())

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let month = calendar.components(.Month, fromDate:NSDate())

    self.selectRow(month-1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `component` function not `components`:
`var year = calendar.component(.Year, fromDate:NSDate())`

or 
`var year = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate:NSDate()).year`